# Dynamic form angular 4 valid add repeate password

Tags: angular, dynamic-forms, angular4-forms

how can I add validation to the password so that they are the same for repetitions?
https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form

Comment: Same Problem: How to set the validation inside the "ControlValueAccessor" Class. In this Case the "PasswordQuestion"